# Apache Solr: More Like This customization

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr to handle my text search needs. Now MLT (more like this) is enabled on f1. f2 is my date field. I want MLT results on f1 but I want them only from a subset of my DB i.e. results from after a certain date (a range query on f2). How can I customize MLT such that I can add this range query on f2 (a non MLT field)?

I am new to Solr as well as Java. Any help however basic will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler, the MoreLikeThisHandler supports CommonQueryParameters. This means you should be able to add an `fq` (filter query) parameter to your search, and filter on f2 being between something and something else. For example:

```
fq=f2:["2011-03-21" TO "2012-03-21"]
```

This says, find all the results from MLT, then add this filtering query.

Comment: This looks like it will help. Will try and let you know. Thanks.